# how to set timestamp in past (manually) with rollbar

Tags: python, rollbar

I'm using (trying to anyway) rollbar to process an error log, that is why I'm looking to manually set the timestamp

according to the docs here
https://rollbar.com/docs/api/items_post/
I should be able to use timestamp with an integer (unix timestamp) passed. 
The data however is not being passed

```
import json, requests

payload = {
  "access_token": "5m1y2f3a1k2e3t1o2k3e1n238151295b8",
  "data": {
    "environment": "testing",
    "body": {
      "message": {
        "body": "Hello, world!"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": 1460652552  # <--- does not show up on rollbar
  }
}

json_encoded_payload = json.dumps(payload)
requests.post('https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/item/', data=json_encoded_payload)
```

Comment: I just noticed that the times do get sent. I see both `Received On : 2016-10-31 11:42:56 am PDT`and `Notifier Timestamp : 2016-04-14 09:49:12 am PDT` I guess this means I may not be able to use this then as the time information doesn't replace the reported timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior your describing is by design, though I agree it's somewhat confusing.  Here's an excerpt of our explanation for timestamps at https://rollbar.com/docs/timestamps/:

> The original timestamp reported to Rollbar by your application is
>   available in the field `metadata.customer_timestamp`. It will normally
>   be a unix timestamp as well. You can see this in two places:
>
> - On the occurrence detail page, the Raw JSON section will include a
>     metadata section. If there was a timestamp in the original report, it
>     will be present as the key customer_timestamp.
> - Via RQL, you can select it as the column name `metadata.customer_timestamp`